# How to pass data which has already loaded component - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

Hy guys, in my angular project after i login, my back end API will generate JWT token and pass to front end. So after that i will decode the JWT token and get some details from that token. So that procedure is done in the login.component.ts So i want to  pass that decode data to my top-bar component. The problem is that the top.bar component has already been loaded in application. Can you help me.

angular 7 cli

### Login.component.ts

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm){

  //some code here for login authentication----------------

  const helper = new JwtHelperService();
  const decoded= helper.decodeToken(result.token);
  console.log(decoded);

}
```

### Top-Bar.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() { }
```

Comment: Read about data sharing through services in angular

Comment: I tried it. but the problem was top-bar component was already loaded . So it's will did not show that new data.

Comment: It will, create a subject in a shared service, subscribe to it in the top-bar component and add values to it in the login-component

Comment: Oh boy... This is the best and worse advice ever. :D For sure it's one of the best approaches IMO. The downside is that RxJs is the worst nightmare to people that haven't got the reactive mindset yet (it seems to be the case here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done in this way:

Create shared service with `loginSubject`:

```
@Injectable()
export class StateService {
    loginSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    ...
}
```

Emit message in `Login.component.ts`:

```
constructor(
  private stateService: StateService
) {}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

  // some code here for login authentication----------------

  const helper = new JwtHelperService();
  const decoded= helper.decodeToken(result.token);
  this.stateService.loginSubject.next(decoded);
  console.log(decoded);

}
```

Subscribe to `loginSubject` in `Top-Bar.component.ts`:

```
constructor(
  private stateService: StateService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.stateService.loginSubject.subscribe(data => {
    // decoded
  });

  ...
}
```

Comment: Hay. after i click the submit button,  in Login.component.ts it will show /// ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined /// this error... can you help me.

Comment: another thing is in top-bar component show this error ///  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: @ThevinMalaka. not sure what caused the error. I've created  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-pass-data-which-has-already-loaded-component-angular-7?file=src/app/hello.component.ts). Check, how it works

Comment: Yeah sure. I will try again.

Comment: yeah friend it's work... @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
}) ////// providedIn: 'root', part missing in my application.. now work it. thank you very much.. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Few of the many ways in Angular Component's Interaction,

1) If Top-Bar.component.html has to be displayed as part of login html then,
   You can pass in the value to Top-Bar.component.ts using @Input variable
   Please read through https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

2) If Top-Bar.component is all together independent of login module, you can have service 
   created and assign the variable to the service and use it for component interaction. 
   Please read through https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4
```